# Smooth circular animation with cubic-bezier timing function CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have defined for an image a keyframe which moves it in a half circular path. I used a linear animation timing function, but it was not smooth enough between the points. After that, I thought about using a bezier easeInExpo function for a better transition, but it just got worse. If I define multiple points at the keyframe the bezier is moving in steps and not smooth at all, but if I define the start and the endpoint it's smooth but it is skipping the path.

My keyframe:

```
.marketplace {
    position:absolute;
    height: 20%;
    top:15%;
    left: 62%;
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    animation-name: marketplace-animation;
    animation-duration:0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
   /* animation-timing-function: linear;*/
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.84, 0);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    visibility:hidden; 
}

@keyframes marketplace-animation {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        top:20%;
        left: 35%;
    }

    25% {
        top:6%;
        left: 41%;
    }

    50% {
        top:4%;
        left: 48%;
        }

    75%{
        top:4%;
        left: 56%;
    }

    99% {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        top:15%;
        left: 62%;
    }
}
```

So my question is if I choose the linear timing for a smoother circular animation I have to define more points or if I want to use the bezier method how can I make it to work smooth and to remain in the path? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two animations:

```css
.marketplace {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px; 
    /* the final position */
    top:15%;
    left: 62%;
    /**/
    animation: 
       x 2s linear,
       y 2s cubic-bezier(0,1,0.8,2.8); /* adjust the bezier to control the curve */
}

/* the initial position */
@keyframes x {
  from {
    left:0%;
  }
}

@keyframes y {
  from {
    top:50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marketplace"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for great tip now it's working fine. Only a question, with these two animation how can I achieve to stay exactly on the path which I have defiened before and be as smooth as now? Because I tried to move the left attirbute on the X keyframe and the top at the Y but I get only strange moves. Thank you :)

Comment: @MrNobody you need to (1) define the initial values of left and top within the aniamtion (the from) and (2) the final values of left and top within the element and (3) the bezier of the `y` animation (keep the other linear). You simply need to find the best curve. Here is a good tool that can help you: https://cubic-bezier.com/